# HTML5 Canvas dragging mask but inverts mask in Safari W7

Tags: jquery, safari, html5-canvas, draggable, masking

Using HTML5 canvas and jQuery I masked out the foreground with a png revealing the background and just the foreground within the png mask. You can drag the png mask to reveal more of the foreground. It works great in Firefox, Chrome and IE, but not on W7 Safari 5.1.7.

In Safari it looks fine on load but once you start dragging the background and foreground switches and the mask inverts.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zboll/Xfw49/)**

```
(function(){

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var background, background2, maskItem, maskItem2, sunglasses;

    maskItemX = 100,
    maskItemY = 100,
    imageURLs = [],
    imagesOK = 0,
    imgs = [];
    draggingImage = false,
    canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset(),
    offsetX = canvasOffset.left,
    offsetY = canvasOffset.top,
    startX = 0,
    startY = 0,

imageURLs.push("http://placekitten.com/940/500");
imageURLs.push("http://codepo8.github.io/canvas-masking/star.png");
imageURLs.push("star2.png");
imageURLs.push("http://placekitten.com/950/500");
loadAllImages();

function loadAllImages() {
    for (var i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function () {
            imagesOK++;
            imagesAllLoaded();
        };
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }
}

var imagesAllLoaded = function () {
    if (imagesOK == imageURLs.length) {
        // all images are fully loaded an ready to use
        background = imgs[0];
        maskItem = imgs[1];
        maskItem2 = imgs[2];
        background2 = imgs[3];
        start();
    }
};

function start() {

    ctx.save(); 
    ctx.drawImage(maskItem, maskItemX, maskItemY);

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";

    ctx.drawImage(maskItem, maskItemX, maskItemY);          

    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, 940, 500);

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

    //ctx.drawImage(maskItem2, maskItemX, maskItemY);


    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";


    ctx.drawImage(background2, 0, 0, 940, 500);

    ctx.restore();
}


function hitImage(x, y) {
    return (x > maskItemX && x < maskItemX + maskItem.width && y > maskItemY && y < maskItemY + maskItem.height);
}

function checkArea(x, y) {
    var     backgroundWidth = background.width,
            backgroundHeight = background.height,
            maskWidth = maskItem.width,
            maskHeight = maskItem.height;

    if (x < 0) {
        maskItemX = 0;
    }
    if (x > (backgroundWidth - maskWidth)) {
        maskItemX = backgroundWidth - maskWidth;
    }
    if (y < 0) {
        maskItemY = 0;
    }
    if (y > (backgroundHeight - maskHeight)) {
        maskItemY = backgroundHeight - maskHeight;
    }
}


function handleMouseDown(e) {
    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    //console.log(e.clientX +' : '+e.clientY);
    draggingImage = hitImage(startX, startY);
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
    draggingImage = false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {

    if (draggingImage) {

        imageClick = false;

        mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

        // move the image by the amount of the latest drag
        var dx = mouseX - startX;
        var dy = mouseY - startY;
        maskItemX += dx;
        maskItemY += dy;
        // reset the startXY for next time
        startX = mouseX;
        startY = mouseY;

        checkArea(maskItemX, maskItemY);
        start();
    }
}


$("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
    handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function (e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function (e) {
    handleMouseOut(e);
});
```

})();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari (v5 on Windows) seem to have some issues with left-over pixels (probably in the alpha channel but I didn't dig deep into it to verify this) and composite modes.

In any case, there are two ways to fix this:

### Option 1: Clear canvas manually

Add a `clearRect()` line to your code and it will work on Safari as well:

**[Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Xfw49/7/)**

```
function start() {

    /// make sure no values are left on canvas incl. alpha channel
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 940,500);

    ctx.drawImage(maskItem, maskItemX, maskItemY);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
    ctx.drawImage(maskItem, maskItemX, maskItemY);          
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, 940, 500);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
    ctx.drawImage(background2, 0, 0, 940, 500);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; /// restore default comp. mode
}
```

### Option 2: Set composite mode to `copy` before redrawing

**[Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Xfw49/9/)**

Set this at the beginning or at the end depending on what you do next, but for the fiddle placing it at the end will do the trick:

```
function start() {

    ctx.drawImage(maskItem, maskItemX, maskItemY);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
    ctx.drawImage(maskItem, maskItemX, maskItemY);          
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, 940, 500);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
    ctx.drawImage(background2, 0, 0, 940, 500);

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
}
```

Copy mode makes sure all pixels are cleared before drawing